# Regular expression to match string from Table having multiple rows

Tags: python, regex, match, regex-group

I am developing a parser to extract string from a Table having multiple rows. Actually each row has multiple lines of strings.

Here is the string from one of the row:

```
'02/03/20        Test String in line1              3431           1.50 hrs.
                 Test String in line2
                 Test String in line3

18/05/20        Test String in line4              1234           .50 hrs.
                 Test String in line5
                 Test String in line6                

                 '''



search = '(?P<Date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}\s+)\s+(?P<Description>\w.*)\s+(?P<Code>[0-9]+)\s+(?P<Hours>[0-9.-]+\s)'

matches= re.search(search, str2)

print("Date:", matches.group('Date'))
print("Description:", matches.group('Description'))
print("Code:", matches.group('Code'))
print("Hours:", matches.group('Hours'))
```

However, It is extracting the content from only the first line and the rest of the rows are ignored. I am getting the output as follows:

```
Date: 02/03/20       
Description: Test String in line1            
Code: 3431
Hours: 1.50
```

Any idea how to make sure, all the rest of the rows are considered?

Comment: Search func find only first match .Use findall func to get all the matches in a given string

Comment: An example would really help

Comment: One more point i have missed set flags =re.M

Comment: Are the date, code and hours only on the first line?

Comment: Yes, it would be one line 1.

Comment: does it have to be a regex?

Comment: Yes, I would ideally prefer with regex. I can consider other solution as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution which uses a regex that either matches your first line (essentially the same as your existing regex) or it matches some words on a line (captured into group `Description2`). We use `re.finditer()` to iterate over the matches, outputting the previous match when we come across a new first line, and adding to the description when we match the second/third/etc. lines:

```
import re

str2 = '''02/03/20        Test String in line1              3431           1.50 hrs.
                 Test String in line2
                 Test String in line3

18/05/20        Test String in line4              1234           .50 hrs.
                 Test String in line5
                 Test String in line6                

 22/05/20        Test String in line7              1852           3.60 hrs.
 30/05/20        Test String in line8              4567           8 hrs.
               '''


search = '^\s*(?P<Date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2})\s+(?P<Description1>\w.*)\s+(?P<Code>[0-9]+)\s+(?P<Hours>[0-9.-]+).*|(?P<Description2>\w.*?)\s*$'

matches= re.finditer(search, str2, re.M)
date = None
for m in matches:
    if (m.group('Date')) is not None:
        if date is not None:
            # new match, print out the previous one
            print("Date:", date)
            print("Description:", descr)
            print("Code:", code)
            print("Hours:", hours)
            print()
        date = m.group('Date')
        descr = m.group('Description1')
        code = m.group('Code')
        hours = m.group('Hours')
    else:
        descr = descr + '\n' + m.group('Description2')

# print out last match
print("Date:", date)
print("Description:", descr)
print("Code:", code)
print("Hours:", hours)
```

Output:

```
Date: 02/03/20
Description: Test String in line1             
Test String in line2
Test String in line3
Code: 3431
Hours: 1.50

Date: 18/05/20
Description: Test String in line4             
Test String in line5
Test String in line6
Code: 1234
Hours: .50

Date: 22/05/20
Description: Test String in line7             
Code: 1852
Hours: 3.60

Date: 30/05/20
Description: Test String in line8             
Code: 4567
Hours: 8
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you can capture multiline.
To capture from multi-lines you need set flag = re.M

```
import re
str2 = '''02/03/20       Test String in line1              3431           1.50 hrs.
          03/04/20       Test String in line2              3211           1.20 hrs. 
          03/04/20       Test String in line3              1111           2.20 hrs.'''


search = '(?P<Date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}\s+)\s+(?P<Description>\w.*)\s+(?P<Code>[0-9]+)\s+(?P<Hours>[0-9.-]+\s)'

matches= re.finditer(search, str2)
for match in matches:
    print(match.groupdict())
    print("\n")

Output:"{'Date': '02/03/20      ', 'Description': 'Test String in line1             ', 'Code': '3431', 'Hours': '1.50 '}


{'Date': '03/04/20      ', 'Description': 'Test String in line2             ', 'Code': '3211', 'Hours': '1.20 '}


{'Date': '03/04/20      ', 'Description': 'Test String in line3             ', 'Code': '1111', 'Hours': '2.20 '}
"
```

Comment: This is not the answer, I was looking for!!. I appreciate all your help. I am looking for matching the string based on grouped parameter

Comment: Could you share more lines(input string) so that I can edit my answer and provide you exact solution

Comment: Attached 2 rows of data

Comment: This is not the solution. You are modifying the string to add date on each line which is not the case in the actual string.